# Connecting to Azure DevOps and TFS with VssConnection and username/password

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a service which import tasks from TFS and Azure Devops. I use Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client 16.153.0

I'm trying to connect to TFS using next code

```
var httpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(new Uri(_settings.ServerAddress), new VssBasicCredential(_settings.Login, _settings.Password));
var taskQuery = "..."
var queryResult = await httpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(tasksQuery, timePrecision:true);
```

This code works only for first time. If I change login/password and import tasks again it still using previous login/password even if it wrongs. And It doesn't work for azure devops.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following code to connect to DevOps. It obtain the PAT you defined in the code:

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(_uri);
    string personalAccessToken = _personalAccessToken;
    string project = _project;

    VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", _personalAccessToken);
```